# ColdFusion and Mobile Application Structure and Security

Tags: jquery, ios, security, coldfusion

**Overview**

I'm looking to start developing iOS apps using HTML5, jQuery, and ColdFusion. My understanding of this is to have jQuery call the ColdFusion API's for all of he back-end functions. Great! My question is mostly about the page structure and API security.

**Application Structure**

In my head I suggested that the actual structure of the app should be similar to this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://foo.bar/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://foo.bar/path/to/api.js"></script>
    <script src="http://foo.bar/path/to/anyother.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

The idea of this is for organizational purposes. I don't want to include any API calls inside the actual app. I would like it to be located on a remote machine. This will allow me to make edits without resubmitting the app to the app store.

**Security**

Will this structure be a security risk? Is there anything I can do to enhance the security of this? Perhaps only allow API calls coming from a mobile device? Or perhaps require some sort of key?

Also, when it comes to the actual API itself. How would the function's security work?

```
<cffunction name="newRemoteResponse" access="remote" output="false" returntype="struct">
    ....
</cffunction>
```

What parameters would you recommend to make this the most secure?

Comment: You need access remote for this work, private functions only work inside the cfcomponents of the same cfc, while you need to access the outside api, you have to use access to remote.

Comment: I kinda figured that one. Thanks though.

Comment: I keep re-reading your question but keep getting tangled up on _"I'm looking to start developing iOS apps using HTML5"_ - a native iOS app is not HTML5, right?

Comment: @Miguel-F No it's not. I'll be using phonegap and Mobile jQuery library's to make a native iOS app with HTML5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make XHR calls to CF from your mobile app, sessions will be respected. That means you can use XHR to call a login method, set a session var on login, and then in *other* CFC methods, ensure that session value exists before you return any data.

Comment: Does this apply to all mobile platforms? Can you authenticate a user with a User ID and Password and then use a SESSION with an iPad application callin CFC Web Services (as you would with a Browser/Login mechanism?

Comment: "Does this apply to all mobile platforms?" Yes.

Comment: Hit enter too fast, "Can you authenticate a user with a User ID and Password and then use a SESSION with an iPad application callin CFC Web Services" Your CFC can check the Session values for the request - so yes.