# How can I implement user authentication for ColdFusion Web Services called from a mobile application?

Tags: web-services, authentication, mobile, encryption, coldfusion

I am developing several Web Services that will be accessed by a mobile application. I have several requirements:

1. Each user will need to sign in with their own User ID and Password (the same User ID and Password they use to sign into the website).
2. Every Web Service request will need to be authenticated to ensure that the request is coming from the mobile app(s).
3. Every Web Service request will need to authenticate the user, since there is user-specific fucntionality built in, and access will need to be blocked if the user's account is disabled.

Let's assume that OAuth is not an option.

In order to ensure that Web Service requests are coming only from the mobile app(s), I am planning to use HTTP Basic Authentication in IIS (the mobile app(s) will need to have a User Account setup in Windows Server and the mobile app will need to store the User Name & Password and pass these in the header).

Next is the User Authentication for each Web Service request. Would it be suitable to encrypt the User ID, Password, and some shared secret key (a "pepper", of sort) with AES-256, pass that encrypted string as a parameter with each request (over HTTPS, of course), and then decrypt and parse it on the server to authenticate? This is the existing plan, but something just doesnt seem right about it - like it's not "secure enough".

What else can I do to properly authenticate users for Web Service requests?

Comment: Looks like we are working on the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539834/coldfusion-and-mobile-application-structure-and-security

Comment: yes, very similar, but I'm not sure a SESSION will work with a native iOS app.

Answer (score 2):

I recently went through this problem and asked opinions from a group of senior people about how they solve the problem. Opinions were varied, but one consistent feeling is that your level of security depends on the use case of your application. Are you doing online banking or storing medical records? Then your security needs may be quite high. Social networking? Maybe not so much.

Basic Authentication is generally fine when encrypted over SSL, ColdFusion works well with it. If you use Basic Auth, make sure to encrypt your traffic with 1024-bit keys or better. Don't authenticate every request with username/password - that's unnecessary. Authenticate the first request, set a session token, and rely on the session token for your identification of users.

Set a polling mechanism from the client to the server to keep the session alive - set the session timeout to 30 minutes and the polling frequency at 25 minutes, for example. Otherwise you may need to re-authenticate expired sessions. Again, how you approach this part of the solution depends on your paranoia level, which depends on what kind of data/app you are dealing with.

Cookies, and therefore sessions, should work fine in iOS apps. If you use sessions to verify identity after authentication, make sure your session cookies are memory-only (set at the server level).

Check the SSL implementation of your server against the Qualysis SSL Test:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

The report will give you a surprising amount of detail about the strength of your SSL implementation.

Lastly, consider implementing two-factor authentication to combat password theft.

If you ignore the SSL advice and plan on encrypting your password and communicating over an insecure channel, look at the Kerberos protocol for a well-known example of how to authenticate securely:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Basic Authentication but that means the client will need to store the username/password in plain text, and also send them over in plain text.  Sending part is sort of fine if it's under HTTPS, but storing username/password in plain text may not be a good idea, unless you're using some secure key store.

Let's assume you have decided that Basic Authentication is the way to go, and you want to make use of the official CF way of supporting that, then you can use [`CFLOGIN.name` & `CFLOGIN.password`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cflogin).  You may also check out [Ask Ben: Manually Enforcing Basic HTTP Authorization In ColdFusion](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1574-Ask-Ben-Manually-Enforcing-Basic-HTTP-Authorization-In-ColdFusion.htm).  In the remote cfc side, always validate the username/password, or return some sort of token and asks the client to use that token going forward.  The token can be cfid+cftoken if you like, or even roll your own that never expires.  If you use cfid+cftoken, and send them over as cookie or in body along with your web service call, I believe you can resume the session if you so choose.